# How to rename a duplicate column using column index?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that has two same name columns, since the first column (agreementID) holds a value, I want to rename the second column) which holds null values to a different name, and different records. I want to use the aggrementID as a key in the future.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8SLE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2voA1.png)

Please help on how to rename the column using column position ore index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val columnIndex = 1
val newColumnName = "new_name"

val cols = df.columns
cols(columnsIndex) = newColumnName
df.toDF(cols)
```

Comment: val columnIndex = 3
val dupagreementid = "dupagreementid"

val cols = df3.columns
cols(columnsIndexx) = newColumnName
df3.toDF(cols)    

the column I want to rename has index=3 but it is giving me an error 

command-2468580744805427:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: String
df3.toDF(cols)
         ^
command-2468580744805427:5: error: not found: value columnsIndex
cols(columnsIndex) = newColumnName
     ^
command-2468580744805427:5: error: not found: value newColumnName
cols(columnsIndex) = newColumnName

Comment: are u sure that it is index = 3?  looks like on screenshots you have 3 columns and 3rd column have index = 2, and index = 3 doesn't exist

Comment: sorry, that was a sample. here is how my columns look like

"agreementId--agrreementType---agreementid"

, I want to rename the third column. the records in the third column(agreementid) are all "null" but the first one holds integer values.

Comment: ok, and it is still 3 columns so 3rd column has index = 2,( index starting from 0). Moreover you can rename your df using .toDf , for example 'val renamedDf = yourDf.toDF("agreementId","agreementType","yourNewName")'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
val distinctColumns = Seq("name","agreementId","dupAgreementId")
val df = df.toDF(distinctColumns:_*)
```

Comment: it still lists all columns with the duplicate one